# dd faster than it should be

Tags: hard-disk, dd, storage, hdparm

When I run the command `dd if=/dev/zero of=tmp.dat bs=1M count=1024 status=progress` on a 500G HDD I get

```
833617920 bytes (834 MB, 795 MiB) copied, 1 s, 829 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 1.41974 s, 756 MB/s
```

which seems bogus (756MB/s !), as I understand mechanical drives on SATA reach a max of about 100MB/s.

To confirm this, I then ran `sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda` and got

```
/dev/sda:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 350 MB in  3.01 seconds = 116.26 MB/sec
```

which seems much more reasonable (116MB/s).

However, even more confusingly, I ran another test: `rm tmp.dat;dd if=/dev/zero of=tmp.dat bs=1M count=512 status=progress` (same thing with half the data to copy) and it gave even more ridiculous results:

```
512+0 records in
512+0 records out
536870912 bytes (537 MB, 512 MiB) copied, 0.576224 s, 932 MB/s
```

Almost a gigabyte per second read/write speed on a mechanical drive!!! And how could copying a file of that size possibly take less than a second (0.576 seconds) on SATA+HDD? Why is there a discrepancy between what dd reports and what hdparm reports? Why does it change based on the output file size?

Clearly I'm missing something here. *nix gurus, please teach me

Comment: Try with files larger than your amount of RAM.

Comment: Quite so: `dd` ends when the data has been sent to the kernel. If you `time sync` the device, it will reveal the missing time.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant AH Thank You! I finally ended using `sync; dd if=/dev/zero of=tmp.dat bs=1M count=512 status=progress; time sync` and I got 512MB/5.125s which is about 99.9MB/s. Finally I can copy ISOs etc. and get an understandable result (and a bonus: apparently I won't corrupt my disks as dd isn't done when it says it is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're observing is called "[Dirty](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics) [Pages](https://www.halolinux.us/kernel-reference/writing-dirty-buffers-to-disk.html)" and is a feature of most modern Operating Systems. The kernel doesn't physically write data to the disk as soon as a file is written to - this allows to more intelligently write data to the disk in order e.g. to avoid fragmentation.

To disable this behaviour run `dd` with `conv=fsync`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Paul gave a great solution in the comments above. This is even more convenient however as there is no need to calculate the MB/s from the `time` command.